# Large scale Meteor site with multiple sections

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

I am building a large scale meteor site where there will be an admin section and a user section.

Is it possible with iron-router to have "/admin//" and "/learner/" and only allow access based on a user permission?

What is the best way to implement this type of system or am I better off building a meteor site for each section (There will be four distinct user types / sections of the site) and some how allowing them to share a MongoDb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the [roles package](https://atmospherejs.com/package/roles) on [Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/).

Comment: Yeah roles is perfect for this situation.